# PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have my rails applications on DreamHost VPS.
By default, it has the following setting.

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
RailsAutoDetect off
RackAutoDetect off
PassengerMaxPoolSize 4
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1200
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 3600
PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 2
PassengerRoot /dh/passenger
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
</IfModule>
```

As you can see, PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp is 2, which means that when multiple requests arrive, 2 rails instances will respond.

However, my test shows different result.

I created the following 2 test pages.

1. http://mis.digitalpowr.com/sandbox/door/hello #=> outputs text 'Hello'
2. http://mis.digitalpowr.com/sandbox/door/long_process #=> sleeps 30 seconds and outputs 'Done'

If I call [1], it responds right away. If I call [2] and [1] immediately, [1] waits until [2] ends. This is against my expectation. If 2 requests are made at the same time, 2 instances should run. Why does it wait until another response ends?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I figured out why it happened.

passenger-status showed that all 4 passenger instances were assigned to 4 applications.
So the specific application can only have 1 passenger instance.

I will request DreamHost to adjust the Max Pool Size.